# Can a Task with while true loop and try catch terminate itself out of nowhere?

Tags: c#, wcf, thread-safety, task, threadpool

I'm encountering a situation where Task stop itself out of nowhere after running for several weeks despite the code was written in the following manner.

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{   
   while(true)
   {
       try
       {
          some logic ....
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {}
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
});
```

Will changing Task to Thread helps in solving the problem mentioned?
The code is built to be wcf service and hosted in IIS. Already turned off IIS application pool restart, so the task shouldn't get affected?

Comment: Could it have been a `StackOverflowException`? These can't be caught. Also `ThreadAbortException` can be caught, but it will be rethrown when the the catch handler exits.

Comment: Is your w3wp.exe worker process alive? I think the worker crashed for another reason and your loop is dead. Your memory stack can be exhausted because an endless loop is dangerous.

Comment: Verified w3wp.exe worker for that particular service is still alive and there's no any error captured in event viewer as well. T.T